# Как создать ожидание ответа от юзера в телеграм боте?

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Пишу бота. Просто калькулятор. Пользователь присылает две цифры и бот возвращает результат вычислений.
Пишу вот такой код:

```
async static Task Update(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken token)
    {
        double price = 0;
        double discount = 0;

        var message = update.Message;
        if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("посчитать"))
        {
            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Пришли стоимость");
            price = Convert.ToDouble(message.Text);

           //итд
        }
    }
```

В общем бот должен взять число из сообщения пользователя, чтобы использовать его в дальнейшем для расчётов. Но бот за это сообщение берёт не сообщение пользователя, а своё же сообщение "Пришли стоимость". Из-за этого программа падает, так как не может текст в цифры перевести.

Судя по всему мне нужно как-то ожидать сообщение от пользователя перед последней строчкой. Что-то типа Console.Readline() как в консольных приложениях. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне это реализовать. Желательно с примером

Comment: Вы желаете создать что-то вроде цепочек? (Цепочка - последовательные команды, когда вторая не может быть активирована без первой)

Comment: Да, именно так. Пользователь последовательно присылает два числа, получая в ответ результат вычислений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете обрабатывать входящие данные по нажатию кнопок в боте как в моем примере используя bool. По другому никак. Также если bool принял состояние true и если пользователь нажал в боте другую кнопку, прописывайте чтобы прежний bool стал false иначе сработает не нужный метод.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Exceptions;
using Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;

namespace BotCalculate
{
    public class TgBot
    {
        //Переменная для активации метода проверки прайса
        bool CheckPrice = false;
        public async void Start()
        {
            TelegramBotClient botClient = new TelegramBotClient(Token);
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var receiverOptions = new ReceiverOptions
            {
                AllowedUpdates = Array.Empty<UpdateType>()
            };
            User me = await botClient.GetMeAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"{me.Username} запущен!");
            botClient.StartReceiving(HandleUpdateAsync, HandlePollingErrorAsync, receiverOptions, cts.Token);
            Console.WriteLine($"Start listening for @{me.Username}");
            await SendCalculate(botClient);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        async void SendCalculate(ITelegramBotClient botClient)
        {
            Message message = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Пришли стоимость");
            CheckPrice = true;
        }
        //Метод получает данные от пользователей
        static async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //Если сообщение не null и тип сообщение сообщение, то обрабатываем текст
             if (update.Type == UpdateType.Message && update.Message != null && update.Message.Text != null)
             {
             var message = update.Message.Text;
             if (CheckPrice)
               {
                var price = Convert.ToDouble(message);
                CheckPrice = false;
                                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, $"Вы присали {price}");
               }
             }
        }
        static Task HandlePollingErrorAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var ErrorMessage = exception switch
            {
                ApiRequestException apiRequestException
                    => $"Telegram API Error:\n[{apiRequestException.ErrorCode}]\n{apiRequestException.Message}",
                _ => exception.ToString()
            };
            Console.WriteLine(ErrorMessage);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```